# Heroku create for an existing app_name

Tags: node.js, heroku

Yesterday I created a new heroku application, but I was not able to upload it, because of errors.

What I did was I entered these commands

```
heroku login
heroku create app_name
```

Now when I try to upload again, I enter

```
heroku create app_name
```

But it gives me an error by saying that
 `name is already taken`.

I know, I was the one to create it.

Is there a command to use an app_name that I created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `heroku create` assuming you're in a Git repo folder then it will set up a Git remote named `heroku` as well as creating the application at Heroku - so that lets you do commands without specifying the app name. eg `git push heroku master` or a heroku command like `heroku releases` for example. If you want to specify the app name you can do `heroku releases -a app_name` to be explicit.